# Anonymous Function Showing End Function Warning

Tags: vb.net, anonymous-function

I am trying out FluentValidation, and I'm converting a C# RuleSet example to VB.NET.

**Question**: Why is VS 2019 putting the green squiggly line under `End Function`, stating the function doesn't return a value on all code paths. Should I be doing something more in the anonymous function to remove this warning? Just ignore it?

Here is the original C# example:

```
public class PersonValidator : AbstractValidator<Person> {
  public PersonValidator() {
     RuleSet("Names", () => {
        RuleFor(x => x.Surname).NotNull();
        RuleFor(x => x.Forename).NotNull();
     });
   }
}
```

Here is my conversion and application in VB.NET, with my own class `ContractDTO`:

```
Public Class ContractValidator
    Inherits AbstractValidator(Of ContractDTO)

    Public Sub New()

        RuleSet("OnCreate",
            Function()
                RuleFor(Function(x) x.CustomerID).NotEmpty
            End Function ' Green squiggly line warning here.
        )

    End Sub

End Class
```

**EDIT:** Note that "Show potential fixes" in Visual Studio shows nothing.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a `Return` if it's a `Function`? If not, just make it a `Sub` instead.

Comment: You can write the function on one line and remove the `End Function`, or do  `Return RuleFor(...)` if it's meant to be returned. Else, do as stated above and change it to a `Sub()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function needs to return a value. Yours doesn't, therefore, you should use `Sub`/`End Sub` instead:

```
Public Class ContractValidator
    Inherits AbstractValidator(Of ContractDTO)

    Public Sub New()
        RuleSet("OnCreate",
            Sub()
                RuleFor(Function(x) x.CustomerID).NotEmpty
                ' Add more lines.
            End Sub)
    End Sub
End Class
```

If you don't need more lines inside your sub, you may get rid of the `End Sub` part like so:

```
RuleSet("OnCreate", Sub() RuleFor(Function(x) x.CustomerID).NotEmpty)
```

Comment: Oh jeez, I feel silly. I took anonymous **function** too literally. Thanks!

Comment: Action translates to Sub() while Func translates to Function(). The C# syntax would not change for either.